# Add files from Dropzone to form

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I want to use Dropzone.js so that the user can select images he wants to upload. But I do not want them to be uploaded on the fly, rather to just be added to form and then submitted the normal way in form array. How can I do that?

I've seen questions like [How to get Dropzone.js to upload files only when a submit button is clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19893962/how-to-get-dropzone-js-to-upload-files-only-when-a-submit-button-is-clicked), but I do not need to upload them at all, I want Dropzone to add files to my form.

BTW, dropzone is in div, not on whole form, if it is important.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the **autoQueue** property to false when you initialize your dropzone instance:

```
var formData = new FormData();

//On addedfile:
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
  autoQueue: false,
  init: function() {
    this.on("addedfile", function(file) { 
      formData.append("file", file); 
    });
  }
};

//On removedfile:
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
  init: function() {
    this.on("removedfile", function(file) { 
      formData.delete('file');
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks. That's not what I wanted first, I wanted to add files to my form, but as I understand one cannot set value on file input due to the security reasons so your answer makes sense. So I will mark it as right.

Comment: do I receive it on the server as a file input?