# how to add files added to the dropzone and send them in an ajax request as if they were input file fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dropzone

I want to receive the files in a formData and send in an ajax request and I want the server to receive it as if it were an input file field.

I tried this: [Add files from Dropzone to form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41036208/add-files-from-dropzone-to-form)

but when I make the request, my server doesn't recognize it as an input file field

```
$.ajax({
        url: args.url,
        data: formData, /*I want the file inside this formData */
        success: function(data){
            
        }, error: function() {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery Ajax File Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add **processData : false** and **contentType : false** to your ajax

As below:

```
$.ajax({
        url: args.url,
        data: formData, /*I want the file inside this formData */
        processData : false,
        contentType : false,
        success: function(data){
            
        }, error: function() {

        }
});
```